# ios set specific orientation for specific views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-x

I am making game which supports only landscape orientation but I am also using a library to share my game video but that share screen require portrait orientation , If I don't enable portrait orientation my game got crash but If I enable portrait orientation to avoid this crash then my whole game become useless by becoming portrait as it is only for landscape.

This is my game Landscape View as shown by figures below,

[image: This is my game LandScape View]

This is the Library Portrait View to Share video

[image: This is the Library Portrait View to Share video]

My Game View after sharing video from library
 [image: My Game View after video share]

Please help me How can I enable portrait orientation for this library to avoid crash
and my rest of the app always remain in landscape and it never goes to portrait orientation.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following method to your application's AppDelegate.m file:

```
// IOS 6

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

In both cases you must also make sure that you have added the landscape only orientation handling code to your game's main UIViewController.

```
// IOS 5

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

// IOS 6

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
   return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement orientation methods to your view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html

I hope this help you.

Comment: my game is in cocos2dx c++ , what I have to do for it :(

Comment: See the documentation cocos2d-x -> http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Device_Orientation

Comment: for iOS you need implement 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation' and 'supportedInterfaceOrientations' methods, for android set 'screenOrientation' for you activity.

Answer (score -1):

In the view controller you want to support orientation override supportedInterfaceOrientations method.
I did like this...

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but actually my game is in cocos 2d x. This method is not working for it.